# How to link to a static library in C?

Tags: c, build, compilation, static-libraries

I use code::blocks to compile my static library. The output result is a libstatic.a file. 
Now, how do I link to my library to use functions that were compiled?

(I tried to use #include "libstatic.a" but my project doesn't compile)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
cc -o yourprog yourprog.c -lstatic
```

or

```
cc -o yourprog yourprog.c libstatic.a
```

Comment: i tried the 2nd one and it works. thanks. i also could be able to configure for code::blocks to work too. :-)

Answer (score 11):

You should `#include "libstatic.h"`, i.e. use the appropriate header file in your code (**that's** why your code doesn't compile) and include the path to your `libstatic.a` in the linker options as one of your input libraries.

This [webpage](http://jrv.oddones.org/lib.html) has some examples on linking to a static library, e.g.

```
gcc -I. -o jvct jvct.c libjvc.a
```

Comment: thank you. finally i got it done on codeblocks and I figured out that #include .h file not necessary the same name as the .a file.

Answer (score 9):

I had to set the library path in my makefile. For this case you could use:

```
gcc -o myapp main.c -L. -lstatic
```

Answer (score 4):

```
gcc -I. -o jvct jvct.c libjvc.a
```

Answer (score 4):

To link purely statically, use `-static`

```
cc -static yourprogram.c libstatic.a
```

Comment: Note that this will cause the compiler to statically link to _all_ libraries, including libc, and will produce statically linked binary. It might be what you want (or not).