# Add .so and .a libraries to Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, static-libraries

I have a makefile which looks like this .

```
DEFINES=-std=c++0x
INCS_GTK=-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include
INCS=-I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/mysql -Iframeworks ${INCS_GTK}
LDLIBS=-lconfig++ -lcxcore -lcv -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lhighgui -lSDL -lftgl -lueye_api -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lann -lpthread -lflycapture -lglog -lmysqlpp -lmysqlclient -lunittest++
DEBUG=-g -pg
WARNINGS=-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-long-long #-O3 -Weffc++
BUILDDIR=build
BINDIR=dist

MAINCXX=${shell find -name '*.cxx'}
TARGETS=${MAINCXX:%.cxx=%}
CXXFLAGS=${DEBUG} ${WARNINGS} ${DEFINES} ${INCS}
LDFLAGS=${DEBUG} ${WARNINGS} ${DEFINES}
include IDEconfigs/Makefile/generic.mk
```

I want to add the following paths of static libraries to the makefile .

```
/usr/local/lib/libYARP_OS.a  /usr/local/lib/libYARP_sig.a  /usr/local/lib/libYARP_math.a  /usr/local/lib/libYARP_dev.a  /usr/local/lib/libYARP_name.a  /usr/local/lib/libYARP_init.a
```

how do i go about doing this .

Comment: that can not be whole makefile, but I'd suggest adding to LDLIBS

Comment: this is the only makefile which is there in the project.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Lets consider your `/usr/local/lib/libYARP_OS.a`.

What you can do is, have `-L/usr/local/lib/` in your makefile as one of the variables. And then you can have `-lYARP_OS` appended to the LDLIBS.

-L is for path to the lib and -l is the lib name here `libYARP_OS.a` will be passed as `-lYARP_OS`.

On the command line you would do something like: `gcc -o main main.c -L/usr/local/lib/ -lYARP_OS`. This should give you an idea.

Comment: How can I add this to makefile?

Comment: Thanks from a C++ noob that just dived into this world.

Answer (score 12):

You can either use an `-L<path>` flag to tell GCC about the location of any library, and then include it with `-l<libname>`. For example this would be

```
$ gcc -o main main.c -L/usr/local/lib/ -lYARP_SO
```

as noted by swair.

Alternatively, you can also supply the full path of the static library and compile directly, like

```
$ gcc -o main main.c /usr/local/lib/libYARP_OS.a
```

See ['Shared libraries and static libraries'](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_25.html) for details.

In your specific case I would add them to the `LDLIBS=` line.

NB: Be careful about linking order, this is relevant when linking programs together. See ['Link order of libraries'](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_18.html) for details. For example:

```
$ gcc -Wall calc.c -lm -o calc   (correct order)
```

works

```
$ cc -Wall -lm calc.c -o calc    (incorrect order)
main.o: In function `main':
main.o(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `sqrt'
```

Also see this similar question: [How to link to a static library in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705961/how-to-link-to-static-library-in-c)

Comment: so i can just do : LDLIBS=-lconfig++ -lcxcore -lcv -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lhighgui -lSDL -lftgl -lueye_api -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lann /usr/local/lib/libYARP_OS.a  /usr/local/lib/libYARP_sig.a  /usr/local/lib/libYARP_math.a  /usr/local/lib/libYARP_dev.a  /usr/local/lib/libYARP_name.a  /usr/local/lib/libYARP_init.a

Comment: That could indeed work, but it might also depend on the inter-dependencies between the objects AFAIK. Did it work?

Answer (score 6):

Append `-lYARP_OS -lYARP_sig -lYARP_math -lYARP_dev -lYARP_name -lYARP_init` to `LDLIBS`.

Warning: the linking order may matter.

Also, be sure that the linker knows that `/usr/local/lib` is a place where to look for libraries, otherwise instruct it with `-L/usr/local/lib` (you could add another makefile variable, e.g. `LIBPATHS` or something similar, to contain the libraries paths).

As a general synopsis, if you have a library `libMyLib.a` in folder `/my/path`, the `gcc` (or `g++`) can be invoked with the following parameters:

```
gcc -L/my/path -lMyLib [...]
```

- `-L` is used to include paths where the linker will look for libraries
- `-l` is used to link a library, which must be passed without the `lib` prefix and the extension

<sub>This question may be useful for a general understanding of libraries usage in C and C++: [How to use Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358745/how-to-use-libraries)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In Makefile , add like this

`USER_LIBS = -lYARP_OS -lYARP_sig -lYARP_math -lYARP_dev -lYARP_name -lYARP_init`

This will link the libraries you required