# linker can't find libraries

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, linker

I can't link my program "set-manipulation" with the libraries it needs.

Here is the message:

```
gcc -L/home/jenia/learn-c-the-hard-way/lib -lset_theory -g -Wall -I/home/jenia/learn-c-the-hard-way/lib/include -o "set-manipulation" main.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lset_theory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'set-manipulation' failed
make: *** [set-manipulation] Error 1
```

Here is the content of `-L/home/jenia/learn-c-the-hard-way/lib`:

```
  /home/jenia/learn-c-the-hard-way/lib:
  total used in directory 29 available 216513716
  drwxr-xr-x  3 jenia jenia 4096 Nov  1 12:47 .
  drwxr-xr-x  8 jenia jenia 4096 Oct 31 11:44 ..
  drwxr-xr-x  2 jenia jenia 4096 Nov  1 12:47 include
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 jenia jenia 6804 Nov  1 12:47 set_theory.a -- 50
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 jenia jenia 9664 Nov  1 12:47 set_theory.so -- 11
```

Here is the makefile which give the error (the makefile of set-manipulation program):

```
PREFIX?=/home/jenia/learn-c-the-hard-way
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -I${PREFIX}/lib/include
LDFLAGS=-L${PREFIX}/lib
INSTALL_DIR=${PREFIX}/apps

all: set-manipulation

set-manipulation: main.o
    gcc $(LDFLAGS) -lset_theory $(CFLAGS) -o "$@" main.o


install: all
    install -d $(INSTALL_DIR)/set-manipulation
    install set-manipulation $(INSTALL_DIR)/set-manipulation

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f set-manipulation
    rm -rf *.dSYM
```

Can someone please tell me how to link my program with it's library?

Comment: if you didn't solved it yet try look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705961/how-to-link-to-a-static-library-in-c

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-L../../PATCH_to_library.a/set_theory.a
```

The library must be named  libname.a/.so

Example :  `g++ Set.cpp -L../../libset_theory.a -lset_theory`

If you don't have named library   libname.a  this dont't link the lib.

```
libtest.a
```

An corect link syntax :

```
g++ (LINK) -ltest
```

You see ? -l   test  don't include lib.
l - lib

```
g++ -g -Wall -L/lib_dir/xx Foo.o Test.o -lset_theory -o test
```

Name of lib must be `libset_theory.a`

Comment: Okay thanks.
I made this change: ` gcc $(LDFLAGS)/set_theory.a -lset_theory $(CFLAGS) -o "$@" main.o`. The error has change. I changed the question to reflected your advice. thanks a lot!!

Comment: gcc -L/home/jenia/learn-c-the-hard-way/lib/ -lset_theory -g -Wall -I/home/jenia/learn-c-the-hard-way/lib/include -o "set-manipulation" main.o

Comment: You don't need to set to the path -L  set_theory.a     , and rename  set_theory to libset_theory.a

Comment: thanks again man. Same message thought. I made the changes to the question to reflect this change.

Comment: Check again my comment, edited. Now i was more clear.

Comment: cool. thank Ramy. That was exactly the problem. Nikita Kakuev said that you can specify the lib name using a colon. Who knows, maybe it'll be useful to you too ;) Thanks again for your kind help

Answer (score 4):

The `-l` argument expects the filename of specified library to be in a specific format. Namely, `-lset_theory` tells the linker to look for a file named `libset_theory.a` (or `libset_theory.so`).

Notice that your libraries don't have this prefix, so you either have to rename them, or use the semicolon and specify a filename:

```
gcc -L/home/jenia/learn-c-the-hard-way/lib -l:set_theory.a ...
```

Comment: thanks very very much. I love the option to use the colon to specify the lib name. Thanks so much. I wish SO had the option to make multiple answers as the good one!!!

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong here, but you don't seem to be including the libraries. I mean, you are icluding the paths, but not the libraries you whish to use.