# Missing symbols Rijndael::Enc::ProcessAndXorBlock and Rijndael::Dec::ProcessAndXorBlock

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, aes, crypto++

I am trying to compile a code for AES however I get an error when i try to do it. The code is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "modes.h"
#include "aes.h"
#include "filters.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

//Key and IV setup
//AES encryption uses a secret key of a variable length (128-bit, 196-bit or 256-   
//bit). This key is secretly exchanged between two parties before communication   
//begins. DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH= 16 bytes
byte key[ CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
memset( key, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH );
memset( iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE );

//
// String and Sink setup
//
std::string plaintext = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide...";
std::string ciphertext;
std::string decryptedtext;

//
// Dump Plain Text
//
std::cout << "Plain Text (" << plaintext.size() << " bytes)" << std::endl;
std::cout << plaintext;
std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

//
// Create Cipher Text
//
CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption( aesEncryption, iv );

CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( ciphertext ) );
stfEncryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( plaintext.c_str() ), plaintext.length() + 1 );
stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

//
// Dump Cipher Text
//
std::cout << "Cipher Text (" << ciphertext.size() << " bytes)" << std::endl;

for( int i = 0; i < ciphertext.size(); i++ ) {

    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << (0xFF & static_cast<byte>(ciphertext[i])) << " ";
}

std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

//
// Decrypt
//
CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption( aesDecryption, iv );

CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( decryptedtext ) );
stfDecryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( ciphertext.c_str() ), ciphertext.size() );
stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();

//
// Dump Decrypted Text
//
std::cout << "Decrypted Text: " << std::endl;
std::cout << decryptedtext;
std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting is given below, this is just a small sample, there is a lot more but it all seems similar to this:

```
  "non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::ProcessAndXorBlock(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) const", referenced from:
      vtable for CryptoPP::BlockCipherFinal<(CryptoPP::CipherDir)0, CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc> in project-53b621.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::ClonableImpl<CryptoPP::BlockCipherFinal<(CryptoPP::CipherDir)0, CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc>, CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc> in project-53b621.o
  "non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned int) const", referenced from:
      vtable for CryptoPP::BlockCipherFinal<(CryptoPP::CipherDir)0, CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc> in project-53b621.o
      vtable for CryptoPP::ClonableImpl<CryptoPP::BlockCipherFinal<(CryptoPP::CipherDir)0, CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc>, CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc> in project-53b621.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm not really sure what the problem is, I've looked everywhere to try to solve this but I haven't found anything that works. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: To figure out how to fix this, we need more information, like platform details and compile/link commands. Shooting from the hip, it sounds like you are *not* linking to `libcryptopp.a`. Or the library is in the wrong place in the compile/link command. Also see [How to link to a static library in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1705961) Crypto++ has a similar report is at [Issue 283: Link failure with mismatched library and program capabilities](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/283). That's due to an ABI break, but I don't believe it applies to you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making your headers `#include "cryptopp/modes.h"` etc? I'm not sure how you have Crypto++ installed on your computer, but this could be the issue since it is a linker problem. Make sure you compile with -lcryptopp. Check out how you are linking together your object files. Explain how and where you have installed cryptopp. Post more information about that

Comment: When I add in #include "cryptopp/modes.h" it gives an error

Comment: I updated the answer to ask you for more information